# Tikz grid with text

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I have a [tikz grid](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#N4Igdg9gJgpgziAXAbVABwnAlgFyxMJZARgBoAGAXVJADcBDAGwFcYkQQBfU9TXfQigDMFanSat2XHiAzY8BIgFZRNBizaIO3XvIFEAbKvEb2AHTMAJZgHMYAAiz2LWMPYCS03f0UoA7MbqklpesnwKgsgAnIESmtoycj6RxGRUanFSOmF6vsjkpMRiQfGhSRFEAByFxZkh2eX6KMQFRRmm9YnhTSQATDXtwQneFc0ibSZDZd15xAAsA5OlDTORBb21HSAW1nb2AB4A+sTTuZFGG4PxO7YOFoxQEDgIK2dEBUKbU6-JRC2knyuWS6b2a-UBS2BIx6xBEEJKUJyv2aC3hdWGSNG+VIcy+1ystwOh16p2RyCMuKBWhue3uj2epKxBSUeMRjVmzNZnWhs36LKpGPZKRE-Mh3MxMIWooR4qF71IBi52wJtLMDyeLxBZKMioFNLuavpmp5a1IfiVjJhBXNAstvLNFp+WNhDttTslrrFgtW8sqSv1RMI7ryRj9epVBvVDODpqijq1zoKcbdCZh-WTXrtwtIGZl3tBJAWufRWb+hXSmZjRHGFbzpZQKha8ZNRACTZTLZQMXbldTszIPbrnDEMCgdgQKFAADMAE4QAC2SAKIBwECQczIYrAzEYjBojHoACMYIwAAo+rSMGBTnAgGgACxg9Cg7EgYDY2VnC6Qm9X6-6W47nuIAHseZ4XiB163g+T4vlob4fjIX6LogAF-ogcwiIBu77keJ7nqCkE3neICPs+r4EIh05zihCwrmuGF0TK244SBeHgYRV7ETB5HwZRoTIUgKj0euwnMUBuFgQRyJEdBpGwRR74CTRSBGCJGFqeJrGgfhEFcXJZFweA-GfipiABOp-zYcBOkcTJ+kkYZilUSAgmIMQwnocQFlaTZ7HSaMsmOQpfFKaZ36oWhDG9ExdQsX5Ul6VBwW8cZYVIWZvQxOpQibr5km6ZxyU8UZCHKRFQhqehQjVNZBV2YFDklc5XCUJwQA) with text in beamer. However, it is somehow moved to the left. How can I change it so that it appears centered in the slide?

Here is the code for the grid:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
                                 & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head] &  & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head] &  & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head] & \Huge i \in I & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head] &    & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head] &    & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head] &    &    &    \\
{} \arrow[rrrrrrrrrrrr, no head] &                                &  &                                &  &                                &               &                                & {} &                                & {} &                                & {} & {} & {} \\
\Huge x_1                        &                                &  &                                &  &                                & \Huge \ldots  &                                &    &                                &    &                                &    &    &    \\
{} \arrow[rrrrrrrrrrrr, no head] &                                &  &                                &  &                                &               &                                &    &                                & {} &                                & {} & {} & {} \\
\Huge x_2                        &                                &  &                                &  &                                & \Huge \ldots  &                                &    &                                &    &                                &    &    &    \\
{} \arrow[rrrrrrrrrrrr, no head] &                                &  &                                &  &                                &               &                                &    &                                & {} &                                & {} & {} & {} \\
\Huge \ldots                     &                                &  &                                &  &                                & \Huge \ldots  &                                &    &                                &    &                                &    &    &    \\
{} \arrow[rrrrrrrrrrrr, no head] &                                &  &                                &  &                                &               &                                &    &                                & {} &                                & {} & {} & {} \\
\Huge x_n                        &                                &  &                                &  &                                & \Huge \ldots  &                                &    &                                &    &                                &    &    &    \\
{} \arrow[rrrrrrrrrrrr, no head] &                                &  &                                &  &                                &               &                                &    &                                & {} &                                & {} & {} & {} \\
                                 & {}                             &  & {}                             &  & {}                             &               & {}                             &    & {}                             &    & {}                             &    &    &   
\end{tikzcd}
```

Here is the complete source:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Scale tikzcd
\usepackage{adjustbox}

% For geometric interpretation
\usepackage{tikz} % 
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes,arrows,%
    trees,matrix,positioning,decorations}
\def\smalldot#1{\draw[fill=black] (#1) %
    node [inner sep=1.3pt,shape=circle,fill=black] {}}

% For graphs
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\adjustbox{scale=.75,center}{
% https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#N4Igdg9gJgpgziAXAbVABwnAlgFyxMJZARgBoAGAXVJADcBDAGwFcYkQQBfU9TXfQigDMFanSat2XHiAzY8BIgFZRNBizaIO3XvIFEAbKvEb2AHTMAJZgHMYAAiz2LWMPYCS03f0UoA7MbqklpesnwKgsgAnIESmtoycj6RxGRUanFSOmF6vsjkpMRiQfGhSRFEAByFxZkh2eX6KMQFRRmm9YnhTSQATDXtwQneFc0ibSZDZd15xAAsA5OlDTORBb21HSAW1nb2AB4A+sTTuZFGG4PxO7YOFoxQEDgIK2dEBUKbU6-JRC2knyuWS6b2a-UBS2BIx6xBEEJKUJyv2aC3hdWGSNG+VIcy+1ystwOh16p2RyCMuKBWhue3uj2epKxBSUeMRjVmzNZnWhs36LKpGPZKRE-Mh3MxMIWooR4qF71IBi52wJtLMDyeLxBZKMioFNLuavpmp5a1IfiVjJhBXNAstvLNFp+WNhDttTslrrFgtW8sqSv1RMI7ryRj9epVBvVDODpqijq1zoKcbdCZh-WTXrtwtIGZl3tBJAWufRWb+hXSmZjRHGFbzpZQKha8ZNRACTZTLZQMXbldTszIPbrnDEMCgdgQKFAADMAE4QAC2SAKIBwECQczIYrAzEYjBojHoACMYIwAAo+rSMGBTnAgGgACxg9Cg7EgYDY2VnC6Qm9X6-6W47nuIAHseZ4XiB163g+T4vlob4fjIX6LogAF-ogcwiIBu77keJ7nqCkE3neICPs+r4EIh05zihCwrmuGF0TK244SBeHgYRV7ETB5HwZRoTIUgKj0euwnMUBuFgQRyJEdBpGwRR74CTRSBGCJGFqeJrGgfhEFcXJZFweA-GfipiABOp-zYcBOkcTJ+kkYZilUSAgmIMQwnocQFlaTZ7HSaMsmOQpfFKaZ36oWhDG9ExdQsX5Ul6VBwW8cZYVIWZvQxOpQibr5km6ZxyU8UZCHKRFQhqehQjVNZBV2YFDklc5XCUJwQA
\begin{tikzcd}
                                 & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head] &  & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head] &  & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head] & \Huge i \in I & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head] &    & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head] &    & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head] &    &    &    \\
{} \arrow[rrrrrrrrrrrr, no head] &                                &  &                                &  &                                &               &                                & {} &                                & {} &                                & {} & {} & {} \\
\Huge x_1                        &                                &  &                                &  &                                & \Huge \ldots  &                                &    &                                &    &                                &    &    &    \\
{} \arrow[rrrrrrrrrrrr, no head] &                                &  &                                &  &                                &               &                                &    &                                & {} &                                & {} & {} & {} \\
\Huge x_2                        &                                &  &                                &  &                                & \Huge \ldots  &                                &    &                                &    &                                &    &    &    \\
{} \arrow[rrrrrrrrrrrr, no head] &                                &  &                                &  &                                &               &                                &    &                                & {} &                                & {} & {} & {} \\
\Huge \ldots                     &                                &  &                                &  &                                & \Huge \ldots  &                                &    &                                &    &                                &    &    &    \\
{} \arrow[rrrrrrrrrrrr, no head] &                                &  &                                &  &                                &               &                                &    &                                & {} &                                & {} & {} & {} \\
\Huge x_n                        &                                &  &                                &  &                                & \Huge \ldots  &                                &    &                                &    &                                &    &    &    \\
{} \arrow[rrrrrrrrrrrr, no head] &                                &  &                                &  &                                &               &                                &    &                                & {} &                                & {} & {} & {} \\
                                 & {}                             &  & {}                             &  & {}                             &               & {}                             &    & {}                             &    & {}                             &    &    &   
\end{tikzcd}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @SebGlav, I hope is better know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram (`tikzpicture`) as a whole is actually not shifted left, it is perfectly centered on the slide. You can see that if you do

```
\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={
    \draw [ultra thick, blue] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
    }
]
```

and set the scale factor for the `\adjustbox` to a lower number:

[image]

This will also show you the problem, which is a lot of whitespace on the right side of the diagram. This is caused by the two empty columns at the end. Remove those empty columns, and you'll get

[image]

Take care not to remove column 13 (third to last) and the `{}` found there. Those are used as end points for the horizontal lines.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Scale tikzcd
\usepackage{adjustbox}

% For geometric interpretation
\usepackage{tikz} % 
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes,arrows,%
    trees,matrix,positioning,decorations}
\def\smalldot#1{\draw[fill=black] (#1) %
    node [inner sep=1.3pt,shape=circle,fill=black] {}}

% For graphs
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\adjustbox{scale=.75,center}{
% https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#N4Igdg9gJgpgziAXAbVABwnAlgFyxMJZARgBoAGAXVJADcBDAGwFcYkQQBfU9TXfQigDMFanSat2XHiAzY8BIgFZRNBizaIO3XvIFEAbKvEb2AHTMAJZgHMYAAiz2LWMPYCS03f0UoA7MbqklpesnwKgsgAnIESmtoycj6RxGRUanFSOmF6vsjkpMRiQfGhSRFEAByFxZkh2eX6KMQFRRmm9YnhTSQATDXtwQneFc0ibSZDZd15xAAsA5OlDTORBb21HSAW1nb2AB4A+sTTuZFGG4PxO7YOFoxQEDgIK2dEBUKbU6-JRC2knyuWS6b2a-UBS2BIx6xBEEJKUJyv2aC3hdWGSNG+VIcy+1ystwOh16p2RyCMuKBWhue3uj2epKxBSUeMRjVmzNZnWhs36LKpGPZKRE-Mh3MxMIWooR4qF71IBi52wJtLMDyeLxBZKMioFNLuavpmp5a1IfiVjJhBXNAstvLNFp+WNhDttTslrrFgtW8sqSv1RMI7ryRj9epVBvVDODpqijq1zoKcbdCZh-WTXrtwtIGZl3tBJAWufRWb+hXSmZjRHGFbzpZQKha8ZNRACTZTLZQMXbldTszIPbrnDEMCgdgQKFAADMAE4QAC2SAKIBwECQczIYrAzEYjBojHoACMYIwAAo+rSMGBTnAgGgACxg9Cg7EgYDY2VnC6Qm9X6-6W47nuIAHseZ4XiB163g+T4vlob4fjIX6LogAF-ogcwiIBu77keJ7nqCkE3neICPs+r4EIh05zihCwrmuGF0TK244SBeHgYRV7ETB5HwZRoTIUgKj0euwnMUBuFgQRyJEdBpGwRR74CTRSBGCJGFqeJrGgfhEFcXJZFweA-GfipiABOp-zYcBOkcTJ+kkYZilUSAgmIMQwnocQFlaTZ7HSaMsmOQpfFKaZ36oWhDG9ExdQsX5Ul6VBwW8cZYVIWZvQxOpQibr5km6ZxyU8UZCHKRFQhqehQjVNZBV2YFDklc5XCUJwQA
\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={\draw [ultra thick, blue] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);}]
                                 & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head] &  & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head] &  & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head] & \Huge i \in I & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head] &    & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head] &    & {} \arrow[dddddddddd, no head]  &  \\
{} \arrow[rrrrrrrrrrrr, no head] &                                &  &                                &  &                                &               &                                & {} &                                & {} &                                 &{}\\
\Huge x_1                        &                                &  &                                &  &                                & \Huge \ldots  &                                &    &                                &    &                                 &  \\
{} \arrow[rrrrrrrrrrrr, no head] &                                &  &                                &  &                                &               &                                &    &                                & {} &                                 & {}\\
\Huge x_2                        &                                &  &                                &  &                                & \Huge \ldots  &                                &    &                                &    &                                 &  \\
{} \arrow[rrrrrrrrrrrr, no head] &                                &  &                                &  &                                &               &                                &    &                                & {} &                                 & {}\\
\Huge \ldots                     &                                &  &                                &  &                                & \Huge \ldots  &                                &    &                                &    &                                 &  \\
{} \arrow[rrrrrrrrrrrr, no head] &                                &  &                                &  &                                &               &                                &    &                                & {} &                                 & {}\\
\Huge x_n                        &                                &  &                                &  &                                & \Huge \ldots  &                                &    &                                &    &                                 &  \\
{} \arrow[rrrrrrrrrrrr, no head] &                                &  &                                &  &                                &               &                                &    &                                & {} &                                 & {}\\
                                 & {}                             &  & {}                             &  & {}                             &               & {}                             &    & {}                             &    & {}                               
\end{tikzcd}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```